# How to cherry-pick interactively

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have hacked on a branch for a while, and this branch won't be merge before long. But there are some commits I'd like to merge in the master anyway.

Is there a way to get an interactive cherry-pick, that would show the commits and their changes, and then let me select the ones I'd actually like to cherry-pick?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do that via the commit graph using  `gitk --all`, and right clicking on the commit that you wish to cherrypick to your current branch.