# Github pull request from a repository to another

Tags: github, request, repository, pull, git-cherry-pick

I have a branch (let's call it **branch1**) in a repository (**repo1**) and I want to push some of its files into another branch (**branch2**) of a repository (**repo2**).
How can I do this in GitHub? I don't want to upload files manually because I need to upload the commits also. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add that second repo as a remote, then you can push to it. Push-syntax allows to specify a branch name to use.

```
$ git add remote repo2 https://github.com/foo/repo2
$ git push repo2 branch1:branch2
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm quite new on GitHub, do I have to use this conde in my git console? Moreover, does this push everything from branch 1 to branch 2? Because I don't want to push all files

Comment: Yes, these are commands you'd type in the console. Yes, this pushes all the commits on branch1 to branch2 of the other repository. Also, do you mean "files" or "commits"? This will be an important detail

Comment: Ops, I badly explained myself, sorry. I would like to push only some files and their related history of modifies, but now I realize that a commit includes many files and maybe it's not possible to keep only commits of the file that I want to push

Comment: What you could do is, from the parent of `branch1`, say `master`, create a new branch, say `tmp`. `tmp` will not contain the changes in `branch1`. Then, you could cherry-pick the commits you want from `branch1` into `tmp` and push that to the other remote. Re: cherry-picking perhaps see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000918/how-to-cherry-pick-interactively). But, again, this will only transfer commits.